# Echo css in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, syntax

I want to be able to put css in javascript like so

```
<script>
  <style>dump bunch of css here</style>
</script>
```

What is the proper syntax to be able to wrap css in javascript?
The purpose of that is to avoid Drupal from deleting my css from page. On save it deletes all css styles, but allows javascript stay. So I want to trick Drupal not to erase my css from page on save by wrapping css in javascript.

This is the CSS I need to put in javascript

```
<style>
dt a {font-size:18px;margin-left:10px; display:block;color:#E45700;font-family: 'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;background: url('http://libraries.idaho.gov/files/arrow-down.png') no-repeat center right;}
         dt {background:#EECC82;margin-bottom:15px;padding: 3px 15px 0 10px}
         dt a:hover {text-decoration:none!important;color:#fff;opacity:0.75;}
         dd {overflow:hidden}
        .key-points {overflow:hidden;padding:0!important;margin-bottom:30px;}
        .key-points li {width:32%;float:left;list-style-type:none;padding:0 10px 0 0;margin-left:0!important;}
        .key-points li.last {padding:0!important;}
        .key-points .text {overflow:hidden;}
        .key-points img {width:56px; height:56px;float:left;padding-right:10px;}
</style>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What are you attempting to achieve? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way? What is the method motivating this irregular approach?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this but you might be able to use javascripts [innerhtml](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) to achieve this

Comment: It always amazes me that everytime I post something on stackoverflow my motives are always questioned. Do you guys really need the whole story?

Comment: @user5248 I think they're questioning because it's a very odd thing to want to do.  It seems like [the x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  It looks like you're wanting CSS on the page, so you're trying to hack your way around Drupal pulling it out.  The underlying problem could probably be better solved with a different approach than adding the styles with JS.

Comment: For example, why can't you put those styles in a style sheet and include _that_ on the page?  I'm not the down voter, but I'd bet that's a big part of the reason.

Comment: The purpose of that is to avoid Drupal from deleting my css from page when I'm saving it. On save it deletes all css styles on page, but allows javascript stay. So I want to trick Drupal not to erase my css from page on save by wrapping css in javascript.

Comment: But the underlying problem, besides Drupal pulling out styles, is that you can't get the styles you want on the page, correct?  Would adding those styles in a style sheet solve it?  Adding JS to insert a block of CSS is highly unconventional.

Comment: I would put them in a style sheet, but right now I don't have the access to the stylesheet.

Comment: I need a quick fix. I will do a proper fix later when I have access and time.

Comment: @user5248 See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. We're not "questioning your motives", we're *trying to help you*. Stack Overflow is not about answering your immediate question, it's about identifying common problems in software development, and building a canonical list of the *best* solutions.

Comment: @user5248 you shouldn't need to do what you need to do to prevent Drupal from doing what it is doing. You're approach and reasoning suggests a fair amount of naivete in what you're doing. That's why it gets questioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this from your script tag.

```
var styleEl = document.createElement('style');
styleEl.innerHTML = `body{color:blue; ... other styles}`;
document.head.appendChild(styleEl);
```